# Evaluate Gaussian Hypergeometric Function $_2F_1(1;1;c;z)$?

Tags: hypergeometric-functions

I need to evaluate the Gaussian hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a;b;c;z)$ for the inputs $a=1,b=1,c\in \left\{\frac{n}{2} : n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0,1\}\right\}$, and $z \in [0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$. Is there a closed form solution for this? If it makes things easier, I am also willing to make the set of possible inputs of $c$ smaller by only considering $c\in \left\{\frac{n}{2} : n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0,1,\ldots,l\}\right\}$ up to some limit $l$.

If there is no closed-form solution what numeric approach/software would be best suited?

Comment: For even $n$ a formula can be found here: http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/07/02/

Comment: $$\, _2F_1(1,1;m;z)=(m-1) z(z-1)^{-2} \left(\sum _{k=2}^{m-1} \frac{\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)^k}{m-k}-\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)^m \log (1-z)\right)$$ $\, _2F_1(1,1;m/2;z)$ can also be expressed in terms of elementary functions ($\arcsin\sqrt z$)

Comment: $_2F_1(1,1;\frac{1}{2};z) = (1-z)^{-1} \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{z}\ \arcsin\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{1-z}}\right)$ and $_1F_2(0,1;c;z)=1$ then make use of http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.5.E16 .

Comment: Thanks a lot! When I tried implementing the solution for $m-1 \in \mathbb{N}^+$, suggested by @JohannesTrost and Carlo Beenakker, I stumbled across a problem.  The results differ from the implementation in GNU GSL, as well as a naive approximation in which I consider the first 90 summands of the hypergeometric series. For example, for $_2F_1(1,1,4,1/2)$, the formula suggested here returns $5.32$ whereas the other two approaches return $1.59$; for $c=3$, there are no differences; for $c=5$, the suggested formula even returns a negative value, which should be impossible.

Comment: Double check your implementation. For $c=5$, $z=1/2$ the result is $\frac{20}{3}- 8 \ln 2 = 1.1214...$. $_2F_1(1,1,4,1/2)=3(2 \ln 2 -1)=1.15888$. Also in the case when I added the first 90 summands of the hypergeometric series. I used Mathematica 11. You might consult Wolram Alpha for example cases, too.

Comment: Do you also get $1.15888$ as the result for $_2F_1(1,1,4,1/2)$ if you use the formula you linked to? ( http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/07/02/?). I get $$(m-1)z(z-1)^{-2}=6$$ $$\frac{\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)^2}{m-2}=1/2$$ $$\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)^{m}\log(1-z)=\log(1/2)$$ $$\frac{\frac{z-1}{z}^3}{m-3}=-1$$ and thus overall  $6(1/2-\log(1/2)-1-\log(1/2))\approx 5.3177....$

Comment: The sum is not including the term $-\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)^m \log (1-z)$ obviously.